# UICollectionView cell apparition animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

I am trying to animate the first apparition of a cell in a collection view  as simple as a ZoomOut + Fade IN of the cells when the collection view is first called.

I have NOT subclassed `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` so far as I did not think it was necessary for such small action and I do not need to further invalidate the layouts once the cells are displayed. There is actually no animations of the cell beyond their first apparition. Reading the apple's developper guidelines on the subject seems to confirm I should not go to the subclass route but still I have not found how to perform the animation I want.

I have played along the lines of defining the cells using `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods then performing a CGAffineTransform sequence in `collectionView(_ collectionView: willDisplay cell: forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` of  `UICollectionViewDelegate` and the proper transformation does occur. Then I was thinking of reversing this transformation by calling a simple `CGAffineTransform.Identity()` in an animation but I have not found yet where (in which of the CollectionView classes method) to place it.

Thank you in advance for your king help!

Comment: Try animate collectionViewCell content not cell

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @canister_exister but where do I put the animation?

Comment: I'm using awakeFromNib() in my customCell class

Comment: I am not using the InterfaceBuilder (full coding for the collectionView). Hence overriding the awakeFromNib() may just never occur :(

Comment: I have found a working solution by way of putting the animation directly in `collectionView(_ collectionView: cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` method. If someone finds something more efficient/elegant, I'd be happy to try it out!